# Best practice to Unit Test a module that depends on the result of several calls to the same function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I want to test, in the most isolated way possible, that a function that I have, returns a sorted array, the function that I have has the shape:

```
import factoryishFunction from './someModule'
import { times } from 'ramda';

export function generateArrayWith(nonDeterministicFunction, deterministicFunction, sizeOfArray) {
return times(factoryishFunction(nonDetermisticFunction, deterministicFunction), sizeOfArray)
.sort((a, b) => (a.value< b.value? 1 : -1)) }
```

So basically I call [times](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#times) that calls a function n times and put the results in an array. Then I call this `factoryishFunction` that using the other passed functions returns an object with attribute value, and then I sort by value in descendant order. Example of how the factoryishFunction could look like:

```
function factoryishFunction(nonDeterministicFunction, deterministicFunction) {
return deterministicFunction(nonDeterministicFunction)
}
```

Where a nonDeterministicFunction could be for example `() => Math.random()` and the deterministic one `(value) => value * 2`

In my understanding, since `factoryishFunction` is doing other stuff to give me back my value, I should mock it up in my test in order to have a really isolated unit test.

Since the result of `factoryishFunction` depend on the functions that I pass to `generateArrayWith`, my doubt is, what is the best way of writing a test where I am not involving the `factoryishFunction` behaviour.

For example I have:

```
    import generateArrayWith from '../ItsModule';
import factoryishFunctionMock from '../someModule';

jest.mock('../someModule');

beforeAll(() => {
    factoryishFunctionMock .mockClear();
});
describe('My module', () => {
        it('returns the values sorted', () => {
            factoryishFunctionMock .mockImplementation((() => {
                let value = 0;
                return () => ({value: value++});
            })); // Each call in the mockedImplementation will return a different value from zero and up
            const noop = () => {};
            const actual = generateArrayWith(noop, noop, 3);

            expect(actual).toEqual([{value: 2},{value: 1},{value: 0},]);
        });
});
```

But I feel that by passing `noop` to the `generateArrayWith` I shouldn't be able to assert those values since they depend on the passed functions. How could I do this in a better way?

Comment: In your example, I don't really see where `times()` (and by extension `factoryishFunction()` are even getting called. It's a bit hard to follow your example with it being as abstracted as it is. It'd be helpful if you gave us a simplified but runnable example of the type of things that your functions do so we can help you figure out how to test them better.

Comment: the exported function generateArrayWith returns the result of times(factoryishFunction, sizeOfArray), so it is called there. Times is one of the things I am testing in other one by asserting that I called factoryishFunction n times (even though this is tested in ramda and probably dont need to be tested).
I will work on a runnable example, I use this abstraction to don't tie it up to my concrete implementation.

Comment: Ah, I see. For some reason my brain read that as two functions, even though clearly the second is returning. My bad.

Comment: I updated with an example of nonDeterministicFunction and deterministicFunction and a simple approach to factoryishFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your general approach is fine. The one thing you can add is instead of doing the same `noop()` for each, give it two different spys. You can then assert that those spys were each called the correct number of times:

```
it('returns the values sorted', () => {
  factoryishFunctionMock .mockImplementation(((nonDet, det) => {
    nonDet();
    det();
    let value = 0;
    return () => ({value: value++});
  })); 

  const count = 3;
  const nonDetSpy = jest.fn();
  const detSpy = jest.fn();
  const actual = generateArrayWith(nonDetSpy, detSpy, count);

  expect(actual).toEqual([{value: 2},{value: 1},{value: 0},]);
  expect(nonDetSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(count);
  expect(detSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(count);
});
```

This should allow you to test all the components of your function without calling `factoryishFunction()` directly.

This does still mean you are calling the real `times()` though. If you want to make it truly a unit test, you could instead mock `times()` and ensure that it is called with `factoryishFunctionMock` return value.

```
import { times } from 'ramda';

jest.mock('ramda'); // mock it to a simple spy in <project_root>/__mocks__/ramda.js

// ...

it('returns the values sorted', () => {
  const factoryishFunctionMockResult = Symbol('RESULT'); // just something to compare against

  times.mockImplementation(() => [{ value: 0 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 1 }];

  factoryishFunctionMock.mockImplementation((() => factoryishFunctionMockResult);

  const count = 3;
  const nonDet = jest.fn();
  const det = jest.fn();
  const actual = generateArrayWith(nonDetSpy, detSpy, count);

  expect(times).toHaveBeenCalledWith(factoryishMethodMockResult, count);
  expect(factoryishMethodMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(nonDet, det, count);
  expect(actual).toEqual([{value: 2},{value: 1},{value: 0},]);
});
```

Comment: Not sure if I should mock times in this case, since its part of the behaviour of function that I am testing, in my point of view the only thing I could mock is the factoryishFunction mock. I post an example of the factoryish function so it is maybe easier to see (it is totally a functional approach and it doesnt have side effects).

Comment: In general, for unit tests, you want to only test what is explicitly going on inside of the function. The nice thing about the second one with `times` mocked, is you wouldn't have to know anything what-so-ever about the behavior of anything outside of the function you are actually unit testing. If you are also testing the behavior of times, that makes it an integration test, not a unit test. That would be fine, but it's not really a unit test.

Comment: i understand the point about times... but my function is using times as part of its behaviour (calling several times a function, putting it in a list and then sorting), I am waiting to see if I can get more opinions on this before accepting it as an answer ;)

Comment: It's up to you, but really, every function in every other function is part of the other functions behavior. `times()` shouldn't be anything special. Your function is calling `times()` and then sorting what it gives back. Just because `times()` calls it 5 times doesn't really change anything about the unit test.